# Some of the directories are missing when I'm trying to create a new Nuxt js project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to start a new project in the Nuxt JS framework with

```
npx create-nuxt-app project-name
```

After completing the installation I realized some of the directories are missing.
Missing directories are - layouts, middleware, plugins, and assets.
At first, I thought I did something wrong then I tried second and third times and the result is the same.
I searched their official documentation and GitHub issue about this problem but I didn't found anything.

- npm : "6.14.12"
- nuxt: "^2.15.3"

Comment: `nuxt: "^2.15.3"` doesn't mean anything by itself, because `^` is a range. And `npx` pretty much takes the latest version.

Answer (score 10):

The latest version of Nuxt is more simple and do have less boilerplate, it follows a simpler tutorial design (to probably lose less users on the road).
You can still add those yourself and it'll work perfectly fine!

This is probably because of Nuxt3 approach and the will to make teach things in a more minimalistic way.

More info here: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/releases
An official answer from Atinux can also be found here: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/821#issuecomment-877653294

---

Also, everything is still explained in the `README.md`, with various links to the official documentation.

[image]

Comment: No man, the previous version of nuxtjs  '@/layouts/Default.vue' component was the default layout. How can I use the default layout in the current version?

Comment: And what about middleware and plugins? whare I can found clear documentation.

Comment: You can check middleware and plugins in the official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware

Comment: Now, Layout is very important you know. How can I use default and multiple layouts for my app? I know it is possible to create a layout component then wrap every page with that. In my previous nuxt project I liked their layout and plugin approach.

Comment: @Hasib it does actually work EXACTLY in the same way as always. Layouts are still here. Middlewares are still here. Create a directory and write a `default`layout file, as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix non working layouts directory like so:

update your package.json file with `"nuxt": "^2.15.8"`
See also: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/release-notes

and run `npm install`

and your layouts folder will work again.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem.
the project nuxt version was 2.15.7. actually the layout page property does not recognize layouts directory and updating nuxt version to 2.15.8 solved it.