# Nuxtjs - What's happend with my nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I create nuxt-app and I opened in the browser and see this
I think this look so different
[image]

[image]

Comment: nuxt is also being updated.. What exactly is broken that you want to 'fix'? If you want an older version of nuxt, just use an older version, but I don't see any reason why you cannot use this version

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact same question as yesterday's: [Some of the directories are missing when I'm trying to create a new Nuxt js project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68335919/8816585)

And, there is nothing to fix really, everything is working as before. Add your missing directories and keep the same flow as before.