# No layout folder in a Nuxt Project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Whenever I was creating a new Nuxt project, there were directories like: `components`, `pages`, `static`, `store`, `.nuxt`, `node_modules` but there are no `layouts` and other directories as of right now.

How can I fix that?

Comment: just create them manually by `mkdir` or GUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably referring to this question: [Some of the directories are missing when I'm trying to create a new Nuxt js project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68335919/8816585)

My answer is in there!

Also, `.nuxt` is a cache directory that you should not touch to, same goes for `node_modules` so far. `node_modules` will be available if you `yarn` normally.

PS: this is based on the assumption that you are doing `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`.

Comment: So in the latest release of nuxt , when you are creating a nuxt project there is no layout folder?

Comment: Yep, the point is to make a gradual learning of Nuxt, without giving to much directories at the same time. More info should be coming by the start of August. Feel free to create a new `layouts` directory and move forward!

Comment: Probably aren't too related but i struggled at first when creating a layouts folder with default.vue. Just quit the server and `npm run dev`

Comment: @MichaelHalim as with any major configuration change of a project, you indeed need a server restart.