# Nuxt 3 files not visible in the directory structure

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I recently started learning NuxtJs and create a nuxt app using the nuxt3 template. The code i used to generate the starter project is

> npx nuxi init nuxt-app

However the the terminal shows that the app has been created and the dev server also starts displaying the Nuxt3 welcome page. But when i load the directory in vs code the folders like pages,store and components are not visible as seen in the screenshot below .

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are importing `<NuxtWelcome />` component from `node_modules` folder. Delete it and replace with `<NuxtPages/>`. Create your own components in folder `pages`. Nuxt 3 imports components by itself, so you don't see them in `<script>` tag. `<NuxtPages />` will do the magic with components in page folder. For example, `Index.vue` component you will see in `/` home page and `About.vue` in `/about`.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is a year old already: [Some of the directories are missing when I'm trying to create a new Nuxt js project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68335919/8816585)

The idea is to have something minimal where you could then add all the needed directories.

Benefit being that if you don't use any `pages`, the final bundle will be smaller (no need to being in Vue router for example). Same for the store (no need to import Vuex/Pinia), server part etc...

It's less of a "you have everything from the start" and more of a "pick what you like the most"!